# Source code versioning of Maven Parent POM

Tags: java, maven, version-control, pom.xml, build-automation

I manage a Maven POM project, that (as usual with POM projects) consists of 1 file: `pom.xml`. There are multiple other projects that inherit settings from this POM. The parent pom does not function as an aggregator; there are no modules defined in it.

Since the POM project has a different release cylce and version history than the projects depending on it, it seems logical to me to put it in a separate SCM repository. The idea is that an automated build job will be triggered on a commit, which can then lead to a release of the new POM to the central artifact repository (Nexus). This leads to the situation where I have a Git repo with 1 file.

**Question**: Is this the normal/desired way to handle source code versioning of a POM project?

Comment: Yes it is. Cause this pom represents an artifact which is used by others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common gloal (or enterprise) parent pom is to be considered like a separated product, it's an artifact on its own, with its own lifecyle and CI job (publishing it to a Maven repository, like Nexus in your case) and as such also with its own version control repository.

Moreover, it may also not be a repository with only one single file, the essensial `pom.xml` file, but also provide further resources. For example, a `site` [folder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html), with its `site.xml` file specifying an additional report or section. In case of a git repository, it should also provide a well documented `README.md` file.

---

From experience, since a global Maven parent POM is used by many different projects, it is also good to take care of its versioning and release notes. For this reasons I would suggest to have the following:

- A `site` folder with the following `site.xml` configuration (as an example):

  > ```
  > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  > <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0"
  >     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  >     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0
  >                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.4.0.xsd">
  >     <body>
  >         <menu ref="reports" />
  >         <menu name="Release Notes">
  >             <item name="0.0.1" href="release-notes-0.0.1.html" />
  >         </menu>
  >     </body>
  > </project>
  > ```
- An additional `markdown` folder under `site` providing release notes for each version. For example, form the `href` above, the following file will be picked up: `release-notes-0.0.1.md.vm`, providing information about its release, which will then end up in the Maven site of the POM.

As you can see, the repository may contain more than the single `pom.xml` file even for a super parent POM. Hence, it should always have its own version control (git in this case) repository.

---

Additional notes:

- A global parent POM is normally applying the `-parent` suffix (e.g. [`maven-parent`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-parent), [`spring-parent`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-parent), [`hibernate-parent`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-parent)). Although not a standard, it's a de fact convention, recommended to follow
- Preferably, follow the [Maven official layout](https://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html) for the POM sections
- From personal experience, avoid having `SNAPSHOT` versions: better to have multiple minor (but fixed) versions of a common parent POM rather than unstable or potentially impacting `SNAPSHOT` versions: it's the global parent pom, its goal is to provide governance and common minimal configuration, it should not introduce instability.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a detailed solution here

[Single click code-versioning (Complimenting cloud-native Architecture)](https://medium.com/deutsche-telekom-gurgaon/single-click-code-versioning-for-microservices-5444d86d1542)

The idea is to use the maven plugin jgit-flow plugin and using Jenkins and this plugin we have created the whole pipeline to automate this process.